# Erro ao instalar gem pg

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gem

Estou com esse erro ao rodar o `bundle install`

> "An error occurred while installing pg (0.21.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
>   Make sure that `gem install pg -v '0.21.0'` succeeds before bundling.
>   In Gemfile:"

Essa é a gem em meu Gemfile: `"gem 'pg', '~> 0.18'"`

Tentei rodar `gem install pg -v '0.21.0'` e então `bundle install` e recebo

> To see why this extension failed to compile, please check the mkmf.log
>   which can be found here:
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/extensions/universal-darwin-17/2.3.‌​0/pg-0.21.0/mkmf.log
>   extconf failed, exit code 1 Gem files will remain installed in
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/gems/pg-0.21.0 for inspection. Results logged
>   to
>   /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.3.0/extensions/universal-darwin-17/2.3.‌​0/pg-0.21.0/gem_make‌​.out

mkmf.log:

> erro ao rodar o bundle install::::Fetching pg 0.21.0
>   Installing pg 0.21.0 with native extensions
>   Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
>
> ```
> current directory: 
> checking for pg_config... yes
> Using config values from /usr/local/bin/pg_config
> checking for libpq-fe.h... yes
> checking for libpq/libpq-fs.h... yes
> checking for pg_config_manual.h... yes
> checking for PQconnectdb() in -lpq... no
> checking for PQconnectdb() in -llibpq... no
> checking for PQconnectdb() in -lms/libpq... no
> Can't find the PostgreSQL client library (libpq)
> *** extconf.rb failed ***
> ```

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa instalar o pg admin server antes na sua máquina.

```
sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib libpq-dev
```

Comment: opa, boa tarde...eu já possuo o PgAdmin4 e mesmo assim o erro continua

Comment: Já tinha o Pg instalado, mas instalei os pacotes: postgresql-contrib libpq-dev e agora funcionou, obrigado.

Comment: No Ubuntu 20.04, apenas o pacote libpq-dev é necessário

Answer (score 0):

Obrigada. me ajudou muito.
Foi só executar `sudo apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib libpq-dev` e em seguida `bundle install`

Answer (score -3):

Se quiser hospedar o BD em outra máquina, não precisa instalar o serviço do postgresql. Bastam as libs. Digite: **sudo apt-get install postgresql-contrib libpq-dev**

Comment: Como está escrito atualmente, sua resposta não é clara. Por favor, pode [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, que ajudarão outras pessoas a entender como isso resolve a pergunta feita. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).